# targeting last image in Wordpress post - undefined amount

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to target the last image in a Wordpress post content. Each post has different amounts of images inside and I want to put title overlapping the last one.

I have the code to target the FIRST image of the post and put the overlapping title in a div which overlaps. Problem is I don't know how to change it to figure out and target the last image instead.

HTML

```
       <?php
            preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
            for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
                if ($i == 0) {
                // only printed when looping on 1st image with a wrapped <div> element
                echo sprintf('<div class="first-img"><h1>%s</h1>%s</div>', get_the_title(), $images[1][$i]);
                continue;
            }
             echo $images[1][$i];
            }
        ?>
```

EDIT - I want all the images to display, but I want to target the last one to put the title over-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `end` PHP function to get the last element of the images array.

```
    <?php
        preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
        if(!empty($images[1])){
            $last_image = end($images[1]);
            echo sprintf('<div class="first-img"><h1>%s</h1>%s</div>', get_the_title(), $last_image);
        }
    ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

EDIT: Try this if you want all images:

---

```
   <?php
        preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
        for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
            if ($i == end(array_keys($images[1]))) {
            // only printed when looping on 1st image with a wrapped <div> element
            echo sprintf('<div class="first-img"><h1>%s</h1>%s</div>', get_the_title(), $images[1][$i]);
            continue;
        }
         echo $images[1][$i];
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: the problem with that is it only displays the last image then, I still want all the images displayed

Comment: See the answer, I've updated to display all the images